# SQLiteException: no such column:, while compiling

Tags: android, sqlite

This is my db helper class, that creates a db when the app is installed the first time.

When I register a new user, if his name is letters like "john", it gives me an exception.
However, usernames like 4, 56 (i.e.: digits only) give no errors. Why?

```
class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, "myDB", null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    Log.d("x", " database CREATED!!! -------------------------");
    db.execSQL("create table userData ("
            + "id integer primary key autoincrement,"
            + "name text,"
            + "password text,"
            + "hero int,"
            + "level int,"
            + "loggedin int"
            + ");");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}
```

}

EDIT:

This is the piece of code where I actually try to update my db.

```
public void login(View v){
    //..some code here
    db.execSQL("update userData set loggedin=1 where name=" + username2) ;
  }
```

Comment: Need to see where you are inserting the record into the DB

Comment: you need to give more code.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein, what? really? why?

Comment: @FrankN.Stein, it WORKS!!!! but why? please write a full answer - i will accept it!

Comment: that question is not about android. it is not even specific to sqlite. It is just about how SQL queries are made.

Answer (score 0):

`if his name is letters like "john", it gives me an exception.
However, usernames like 4, 56 (i.e.: digits only) give no errors. Why?`

Wild Guess: You forgot to enclose `John` in single quotes, i.e.: `'John'`.

The reason for this being that `John` is a string.
And strings must be delimited by single quotes (**'**)

Be aware that, if the string itself contains a quote (or apostrophe), i.e. `'I'm aware of that'`, then the apostrophe it has to be **doubled**, i.e. `'I''m aware of that'`.

---

If you don't want to hassle with quotes, there's a better way to make Android handle it for you: bound parameters.

In practice, all the values in your query should be replaced by a question mark placeholder (**?**).

And you give the query a String array containing all the values to be replaced.

This way you are also protected against SQL injection.

---

An example would clarify the concept better:

```
// Two values to be passed...
final String sql =
    "SELECT date, score FROM " + DB_TABLE +
    " WHERE strftime('%Y', date) = ? AND " +
    "CAST((strftime('%m', date)) AS INTEGER) = ? ORDER BY date DESC";

// ... into the string array parameter of the rawQuery() overload
final Cursor cur =
    db.rawQuery
    (
        sql,
        new String[]
        {
            String.valueOf(CLS_Utils.yearUsing),
            String.valueOf(month)
        }
    );
```

---

Note.

The same technique applies to `execSQL()` as well.
Therefore it can be used on INSERTs, UPDATEs and DELETEs as well.

Answer (score 0):

All strings in sql must be enclosed by '. Quoted from https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html:

**"A string constant is formed by enclosing the string in single quotes ('). A single quote within the string can be encoded by putting two single quotes in a row - as in Pascal. C-style escapes using the backslash character are not supported because they are not standard SQL."**